# Cryptsetup does not accept passphrase after installation

Tags: xubuntu, passphrase, cryptsetup

I used the xubuntu 13.04 installer and selected german keyboard layout. Afterwards i checked that I want to install with encryption via LUKS on a LVM. There I entered my passphrase and the setup install the system.

After a reboot i have to enter my passphrase, but it seems that cryptsetup my passphrase.

I tried to use keys like us layout and also german keymapping but neither of them worked.

Some help apreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try to redo the installation and go to 'Try Ubuntu' before doing the actual installation. There you can set the keyboardlayout and it should become effective.

There is even a comment about this on the [bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1047384/comments/18).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 16.04.1.

It turned out that when defining the passphrase in the installer, the keyboard was using the US layout, but I thought it had my native layout. This means that when I was setting the passphrase, it was recorded differently from what I believed.

After reboot, I was asked for the passphrase using the native (in my case, Finnish) layout that I had selected in the installer.

The solution was to *reverse*-map the passphrase: I imaginined that I was pressing the keys according to my native layout, and wrote down the symbols that would be output if I pressed the key in the same position in a US layout. This was the actual passphrase. Now when I entered it using my native layout at startup, the passphrase was accepted.