# Help! Passphrase no longer decrypts my disk

Tags: cryptsetup

For some unknown reason I can no longer decrypt my disk with the passphrase that I had been using for months. I thought that this could be a [keyboard layout problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/587934/643185), therefore I have also tried typing my passphrase as if I was using the English(US) keyboard layout, like [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/832368/643185) suggests, but it fails to decrypt the disk.

What should I do now?

I have an Ubuntu Live USB image in one of my usb flash drives. Can I use it to solve this?

Comment: You can use the Ubuntu live image to check if your keyboard is working... if so then you have a problem with your password/encrypted disk and I think that your disk is gone.

Comment: @LilloX my keyboard is working correctly